# Simplify complexity for parsing 2 json files in 2 cycles

Tags: php, mysql, json, parsing, time-complexity

I am parsing 2 `JSON` files and saving only some necessary data into MySQL database right away. Problem is in execution time of this script, since there is pretty much over 1000 games in the json file.

What the script does is that it parses first json file which is a list of games, where only some of those games are possible to get embed code from.

Steps to get what I want:

1. Parse `$game_list_url`
2. Decode and save `game_id` into `$game_id`

Now, since I got `$game_id` from `$game_list_url` file, I can parse another file, which is a specific `json` file of the game I want to get info about - info whether it has `embed code` which is final target of this entire script. A way of finding out if the game's `json` file has `embed` v variable is to check if the `$webmaster_game == 1`. If it is, thats the game I want!

So moving on from step 2, the next steps would be:

3. Parse `JSON` file of a specific game --> `$get_game_by_url`
4. Decode and save `webmaster_game` into `$webmaster_game`
5. Check if `$webmaster_game == 1`

   a) if not, `break` out of inner cycle and go for next `game_id`

   b) if yes, decode and store other info into variables and `execute() query`

This script takes too long to execute - it runs over `max_execution_time`. What could dramatically simplify the complexity of this or how could I change it so it doesn't take so much time?

**EDIT**

Regarding to suggested answer as duplicate, extending `php_execution_time` does not solve my problem, since I have already done it and it does **NOT** simplify complexity of my script.

I am looking for a way to reduce the execution time to shortest possible. Can saving the json files save some time, are there any other options?

See my code below

```
<?php

include './db/connect.php';

$game_list_url = 'https://webmasters.miniclip.com/api/games/en.json';
$data = file_get_contents($game_list_url);
$json = json_decode($data,true);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO game     (game_id, name, main_category_id, 
                                                    width, height, embed,
                                                    big_icon_path, small_icon_path
                                                    ) 
                                                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

foreach ($json as $row){
    //decode json vars to php vars
    $game_id            = $row['game_id'];

    //parse game by game_id to check if it is possible to get embed code of the game
    $get_game_by_url = 'https://webmasters.miniclip.com/api/games/'.$game_id.'/en.json';
    echo $get_game_by_url;
    echo "\n";
    $data2 = file_get_contents($get_game_by_url);
    $json2 = json_decode($data2,true);

    foreach ($json2 as $row2){
        $webmaster_game     = $row2['webmaster_game'];
        //if webmaster_game != 1 then skip this game, because we cannot get embed code from miniclip
        if($webmaster_game != "1")
            break;
        $small_icon_path    = $row2['small_icon'];
        $big_icon_path      = $row2['big_icon'];
        $name               = $row2['name'];
        $main_category_id   = $row2['main_category_id'];
        $width              = $row2['width'];
        $height             = $row2['height'];
        $embed              = $row2['embed'];

        $stmt->bind_param("isiiisss",     $game_id, $name, $main_category_id,
            $width, $height, $embed,
            $big_icon_path, $small_icon_path
        );
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

//script done, close all connections
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: why not use cache？

Comment: I have never used cache, this is also my first time with parsing `json` files..any "simple" solution which will do what I want will be okay with me

Comment: I would bet that most of the time in this script is taken up making the call to `webmasters.miniclip.com` in the loop

Comment: @winlans I am interested, use what cache?

Comment: @RiggsFolly so what you want to suggest is download the file first and then parse it? Or as winlans mentioned cache, maybe caching the file would help with faster file reading?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by that

Comment: According to their API docs, `https://webmasters.miniclip.com/api/genre/432/en.json` will get you only the webmasters games. But if you want to get the actual embed code for each one, you'll still have to make a separate API request for each game, which will still be slow. But not AS slow.

Comment: @Don'tPanic well that's what I am doing right now, isn't it? I am parsing list of all games, and then I parse every game's file separately.

Comment: Do you run this code very often?

Comment: Yes, it will just let you eliminate the `if($webmaster_game != "1")` bit, because that will return only the webmaster games rather than all the games.

Comment: btw, with your current code, `if($webmaster_game != "1") break;`, you probably want `continue` rather than `break`, otherwise it will stop the loop the first time it encounters a non-webmaster game.

Comment: @RiggsFolly well, I will run this code only when I will want to update my database for new games, pretty much. When I get all data I want into DB, no need to parse over and over.

Comment: @Don'tPanic it runs fine now, it did not stop on first non-webmaster game.

Comment: @RiggsFolly maybe file cache is fit for his.

Comment: @winlans So where are we going to find the mythical cache full of the info we are interested in?

Comment: Define _Script takes to long to run_ Do you mean it blows the `max_execution_time`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, it does. I have added that into my question just now.

Comment: @RiggsFolly http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html

Comment: @winlans 1) Does this look like Symfony code to you? 2) You have to load a cache, they are not magic! So OP would have to make all the calls to the remote server anyway to load the cache with anything useful.

Comment: I have tried to edit the first file as @Don'tPanic mentioned, it did go much faster than before, but it still takes about 40 seconds to save 270 games.

Comment: **Are we worrying about a script that you run once in a while that takes 40 second to run????** When I say we, I mean everyone else, I no longer care

Comment: _but it still takes about 40 seconds to save 270 games_ **No!** It probably takes 38 seconds to ask for and be given the data by the remote website

Comment: @RiggsFolly I meant it takes 40 seconds to finish the process. And this is not a duplicate, since I am asking about simplifiying complexity, not how to extend `php_execution_time`, since I have already done it.

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.